# how to create date format during table creation in query browser

Tags: mysql

how to define date format during table creation,for example i need to create table with date field in sql query browser but i don't have any idea to create date in this format `dd-mm-yyyy`.
Whether is it possible to create table with date field in this format.

Comment: This is what answer for my question .create table my_tab(my_date date not null default '00-00-0000');

Answer (score 0):

The closest you will come to dd-mm-yyyy as a data type is `date` but that is yyyy-mm-dd. You are basically looking to create a field as a `varchar` and create a custom date format prior to your insert query to be inserted.

http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses **`YYYY-MM-DD`** as date format, but you can show dates in other formats on your query using the **`DATE_FORMAT`** function.

For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydate,"%d-%m-%Y")  
FROM mytable
```

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question.What i am asking is how to create table with date field and the date field should be in my format like "dd-mm-yyyy" but the default in mysql during table creation is "yyyy-mm-dd" .Thank you so much for your replay and i am waiting ...

Comment: i undestood your question but that is not posible. mysql always uses yyyy-mm-dd to store dates allowing values between '1000-01-01' and '9999-12-31'. to show a date in other format you can use DATE_FORMAT and to convert a string into a date you can use STR_TO_DATE.

Comment: i got answer friends ....and thank you to all....use this statement during table creation for date field 
create table t_name(date not null default '00-00-0000');